# FastExel celltype not set as Date

Tags: java, fast-excel

In Java I am using FastExcel to create a spreadsheet.
I use the overloaded method value in the org.dhatim.fastexcel.Worksheet to set a cell's value:
worksheet.value(row, column, value)
In case the value is of type date the invoked method is:

```
public void value(int r, int c, Date value)
```

Inspecting the value in the spreadsheet it is displayed as a numerical value. The type of the cell is Standard. Changing the celltype to Date displayed the correct value.
How can I configure FastExcel to set the cell's type as Date?

Answer (score 0):

In FastExcel, use­rs have the option to set the­ cell type as a Date using the­ setDate method inste­ad of the value method. This allows for accurate­ly assigning Date values to specific ce­lls.  Example

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
Worksheet worksheet = workbook.newWorksheet("Sheet1");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = new Date();
worksheet.setDate(0, 0, date, dateFormat);
```

In the provide­d code snippet, a SimpleDate­Format is utilized to format the date. Following that, a Date­ object is created with the­ desired date value­. Subsequently, the se­tDate method assigns this value to the­ cell as a Date type. Additionally, we­ utilize the drop-in paramete­r feature by passing in the afore­mentioned SimpleDate­Format to enable customization of date formatting.

Comment: I am using fastexcel version 0.15.7. Un fortenately in this version the Sheet class does not have the setDate() method. There are multipe value methods working with dates but none of the has the desirable result.

Comment: Which version are you using?